UK visa - Should I exclude income I'll earn between submitting my application and the trip, since I can't provide evidence of saving it for the trip?
I plan to apply for a visitor visa with a sponsor in the UK (London) for a 4-day trip. I am currently employed and saving my salary. By the time I submit my visa application, my bank statement will show two months’ worth of savings, even though my total budget for the trip will be three months of savings. My sponsor will cover most of my expenses, and I intend to use only 16% or less of my own funds for the trip.
Since I cannot provide evidence in my application that I will save my third monthly salary specifically for this trip, should I exclude it entirely from my explanation?
Edit: I do intend to show 6 months of bank statements!

By "third salary" do you mean "the income you'll receive between the time of application and the trip"? Normally I would use the phrase "third salary" to refer to payment for a "third job", not a paycheck from my one and only job.

If this is your first UK visa (and maybe even if it’s not), two months’ statements /evidence of savings are unlikely to be sufficient, notwithstanding having a sponsor. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

I also initially read "third salary" as referring to income from a third job, in which case the answer would have easily been: "no, you should never exclude anything". It wasn't until I read @MichaelSeifert's comment that I realised there was another (and in this case: more plausible) way to read that. It doesn't matter which months income you show (as long as they are recent), you just need to show that you have an income and normal expenses allow you to save up for the trip.

@MichaelSeifert sorry for the confusion, just edited it! Hope it makes sense now.

I've suggested what I think is a clearer title. Feel free to revert it if you prefer your version.

IIRC, the visa application asks how much savings you have. It doesn’t ask how much savings will you have at your intended travel date.  So you cannot include savings from future income in your application.
Note that having a sponsor isn’t a guarantee of success. You still need to show that you meet the eligibility rules.

But should I be honest and tell them what my financial plan is?

@Bini Well, honesty is always the best policy. However IMHO it would be far better to wait the extra month before you apply. IANAL but I really don’t think that explaining your financial plan will carry much weight with UKVI.
